# Getting empty result in Tesseract from picture, but good result from screenshot of aforementioned picture

Tags: tesseract

Tesseract version, from the --help command in macOS 10.14.6. Mojave

```
tesseract 4.1.1
 leptonica-1.79.0
  libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 9d : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.1.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.1.0 : libopenjp2 2.3.1
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
```

I'm trying to extract information from personal Id cards, and while the quality of the source pictures can vary a lot it's been working fine for the most part after I do some pre processing. However, there's a weird issue I'm running into. This is all after going through some pre-processing like deskew, thresholding, etc on the picture, and before running Tesseract on it.
When executing the bash command, for example

```
tesseract inputImg.png out2 -l jpn
```

There are some instances (20%~ of my pictures set) where the output is empty. Well, it actually has a single line break, but that's it. I would expect at least some garbage output from low quality pictures, but instead I've been getting nothing at all.

The command line only shows the following information message, as it does every time it's executed regardless of whether it manages to extract text from the picture or not.

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
```

I don't know why it's getting **nothing** out of the picture. The weirdest thing is that if I open that picture in [Preview](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/welcome/mac), take a screenshot (with the builtin macOS screenshot feature) of it, and run the same tesseract command on the screenshot, **it outputs the expected data!** Now, I don't really know what happens behind the scenes when taking a screenshot, but the content of the picture is pretty much the same so it's surprising that the result is so widely different. I assume that the problem is the file itself, but I don't know how to go around solving it.

Also, the resolution of the source image and the screenshot is roughly the same. One of them for example, is 1357 x 938, while its screenshot version is 1342 x 915.

What I've tried:

- Stripping the picture's metadata with [ImageMagick's strip command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip)
- Using different --psm values on the tesseract command
- Using different threshold values on the source image (from 30% up to 80%, on 5% increments)
- Manually cropping the original image to remove unneeded borders

Same result every time. Again, it feels as if the file itself is messed up, but I don't know what the exact problem could possibly be.
Suggestions?
I'm at a point where I'm thinking of adding junk data to the picture just to see if it does *anything* at all.